# Is this legal? And should we use 2 by 8s?

Tags: joists

I posted a couple of days ago about joists not reaching the end of the wall, and it was only a subsection.

We’ve stripped off all floorboards and this is what we see.

[image]

Now the question is, these joists measure as 2"x 4"s, Surely the new ones we put in should be 2"x 8", no?

Not sure how they would fit and I’m not sure why they weren’t originally 2"x 8" either. There’s a good meter between the 2 bottom beams.

Is this common?

What should the span between beams be when laying 2"x 4"s or 2"x 8s"?

See full video with joists taken out here:

https://streamable.com/4hb7w1

Comment: Legal or not, that's a mess!  It looks like they just built this on the fly using scrap lumber they had on hand.  It looks like it's being supported by a few rocks.

Comment: I know right, p-take. What you recommend we use/distance between beams? Just curious what the regs are :)

Comment: Building codes are going to vary place to place.  But generally 2x4s are NOT used as floor joists.  You've come this far, it makes no sense to me to put new flooring down over this disaster.  I'd pull it all out, find something to support it or put in some footings, re-frame the joists with 2x8s or larger depending on what's required in your area for the use of this area, and then proceed with subfloor and finish flooring.

Comment: Looks old. *i.e.* the 2x4's are probably actually 2 X 4, not modern 1.5 X 3.5 (or less) and likely there were no standards in play so the builder could make it to suit, and it lasted from whenever that was to now. Honest, full-size 2x4's spanning only a meter will take a good deal of loading. Sure, rebuild it to suit modern standards, but don't get *too* bent out of shape by something that looks to have lasted 70+ years give or take...

Comment: I'm thinking that the floor as well as subfloor was removed for a reason.  Like perhaps it was sagging or springy.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Not only was this probably "real" 2x4's (i.e. rough cut), but even if it is pine it will be a lot harder than what we get in the lumber yard today.  Years ago, the pine harvested was older than what we harvest today, meaning it was a lot harder too.  All in all, this setup probably made sense at the time.

Comment: Yeah the house was built in 1956 so I suspect this might have been there since then maybe? We pulled off the flooring and subfloor because we are going to do a wet room and came across this disaster of a joist system. They are definitely 2 inch by 4 inch

Comment: I’m guessing we have to cut out a lot more of brick to fit the 8 inch required? Also, I’m assuming 2 by 8s should be more than enough for a wet room. In this setup above, in terms of the horizontal joists, what would be the recommended number of joists we put down (and their size), and what about the number of vertical joists (vertical relative to the floor plane of course).

Comment: What is under it? looks concrete-ish, you mention cutting away brick? If that's a solid base, it's silly to cut it away to fit 2x8 lumber if smaller (rot-resistant treated if in contact with masonry) lumber would be directly supported by whatever the base layer is - it's not going to move if that's a solid base, and with short-to-no span between supports you don't "need" 2x8s.

Comment: Ecnerwal yep it’s definitely concrete.

Comment: Supposing we didn’t cut away anything and 2 by 4s would be supported by the concrete base, then would that be enough to support the wet room?

Comment: The way you've described it the 2x4's sit directly on the concrete.  Therefore, the concrete will bear the load so you just need something strong enough to not squish under your floor.  Sounds like 2x4's are a good idea.  Per Ecnerwal's suggestion, use treated lumber for this.

Comment: What is a "wet room"? Unless the floor will be soaked in water, that really doesn't impact what or how the floor is framed. The critical elements are the spans. Could you give us dimensions for this room?

Comment: Hey, so brick to brick length ways it’s 2.35cm and width is about 150cm

Comment: I’ve heard that if you’re doing a wet room you need extra support near the shower tray, but I suspect that’s just adding some noggins or battens the height of the shower tray onto the joist. Will upload a video on Streamable so you guys can see. Just cleaning up the floor.

Comment: Just posted a video of the joists removed so it can be judged better! See original post edit

Answer (score 2):

> What should the span between beams be when laying 2"x 4"s or 2"x 8s"?

If your question is only what should the floor joist spacing be then; if you go with 2"x 8" floor joist    16 "  on center (OC) will be sufficient.

I would not use 2"x 4"s.

If you use 2"x 6"s then i would go 12" OC.

If your question is how should i rebuild this then; I would rip it all out, Bolt rim joists to the concrete wall with anchor's and run the joist from wall to wall (*left to right in the photo*) hung on the rim joist with Simpson joist hangers and then re-do the plumbing.

Comment: Per the OP's additional information, the 2x4's currently sit directly on a concrete floor.  Kinda makes the point moot as to joist spacing.

Comment: @tnknepp I had not read that "additional information"  That may have been added as i was writing my answer.  My answer addressed the question of proper joist spacing. If the joists are sitting on the concrete then 16" OC  still applies.

Comment: Thanks, I figured you missed that.  Why the 16" spacing?  Is this to limit flex in subfloor?

Comment: 16" OC is important, not for load on the joists (in _this_ case), but the span of the sub-floor they're supporting. Virtually all modern flooring materials expect a 16" or 24" OC.

Comment: You say “If you use 2x6’s then I would go 12” oc.” If you go 12” oc, then what is the span and what is the load it will support?  (Did you know that 2x4’s at 16” oc spanning 3’ can support about 200 lbs. per square foot? )

Comment: Might want to watch the video I put in the original post. I thought the 2 by 4s were sitting on concrete. I still think they are but it’s a little confusing as there seems to be a concrete slate in between a set of bricks, above the slate is where the joists were sitting (see video)

Comment: I know I've previously had some responses but I've had another idea.

How feasible is it to use 2 by 6s, and rather than put the joists inside the wall, bolt/anchor the 2 by 6 bearers (horizontal joists), then put the 2 by 6 joists across the 2 bearers using joist hangers? We'd need to pack the bricks that have been cut for the previous 2 by 4s.

Can this work? Do the 2 bearers have to be elevated from the floor or leave a certain distance from the brick wall when being bolted in?

What would also be the recommended span of the joists?

The room is 2.35m by 1.47m brick2brick as an FYI.